# Trying to create a login screen With Adndoid SDK 2.3.3

Tags: android

I am Completely new to Android SDK and very new to writing code in general. I have been monkeying with the software and following a tutorial on how to make a login for my app but I just can't seem to get it to work. Below is my .Java Code. I can tell that the error is in line 32-42, I don't know why I it does not detect .settext or .SetOnClickListner. Any help would be great.

```
package com.example.inventory;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText User;
private EditText Password;
private TextView Info;
private Button Login;
private int counter = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    User = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
}

Info.setText("No of attemps remaining: 5");

Login.SetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
    validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
}
};
```

}

```
private void validate(String userName, String userPassword) {
    if ((userName.equals("Admin")) && (userPassword.equals("Pass"))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        counter--;

        if (counter== 0){
            Login.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your .setText() code is outside of the onCreate method. There is not a process to call the .setText() method. Just move the code inside of the bracket above it. Same goes for your OnClickListeners. You were also missing a parenthesis at the close of your OnClickListener.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    User = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    Info.setText("No of attemps remaining: 5");

    Login.SetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){
        validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also, you will find it to be more convenient as you progress with the application if you add the name of the view to your variables in the java code for easy reference. (i.e. userInputEditText or userEt and so on...). As for the xml reference ids, underscores are common practice instead of camel-casing (i.e. et_input_name or et_name).  Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: If this was helpful to you, please remember to accept my answer! ;)